# Page design for a row is not coming properly

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I want both the map and pie chart in a row, but it is coming in 2 different row. Any Help would be appreciated.

Here is link:
http://jsfiddle.net/2emnt8m3/14/

Image for the design: 
[image: Error part]

```
  <div class="container">
```

Comment: `col-md-*` makes it into different rows for smaller device. You need to mention classes for smaller device too. `col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootsrap grid system scales up to 12 columns. The number after the class prefix represents the width in columns. Each column type works differently on multiple devices (`.col-xs-*` remains horizontal at all times, while the others are collapsed to start and horizontal above breakpoints).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <!-- map -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <!-- chart -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For details, see the Bootrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

You need to change line 7067 from

```
var vis = d3.select('body')
```

to

```
var vis = d3.select('#piechart')
```

See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/h0rnzk4s/.

Comment: I try it, but it doesn't come. Would u please!!

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to place the chart inside the second column, not in the body.